# Res.json/backend express issue

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I in the process of making my first MERN stack application.  I am having some problems querying an entire collection from MongoDB and saving it into a React Class state.  The following is my code.

```
class MyMap extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            addMarker: {},
            strAdd: "",
            displayAdd: "",
            date: "",
            pictureLink: "",
            description: "",
            modalOpen: false,
        };
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.addMarker = this.addMarker.bind(this);
        this.getAddress = this.getAddress.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        let res = this.props.loadHouses();
        console.log("Res Component Did Mount");
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({
            data: res
        });
        console.log("Res This State Data");
        console.log(this.state.data);
    }
}
//Backend loadhouses
export const loadHouses = function () {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {
        console.log("Test House Actions!")
        return axios.get('/api/house', tokenConfig(getState))
            .then(res => res.data)
            .catch(function(err) {
                dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
            });
    }
}
///api/house
router.get('/', auth, (req, res) => {
    console.log("test");
    House.find({}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(result);
            return res.json(result);
        }
      });
});
```

Console.log(result) right above here returns:

```
[
[0]   {
[0]     _id: 5ffd1c33820fe62e4983cc19,
[0]     address: '1735 York Avenue New York County, New York, 10128, United States',
[0]     latitude: 40.77952599242572,
[0]     longitude: -73.94478734434928,
[0]     pictureLink: 'Test1',
[0]     description: 'Test1',
[0]     date: '2021/1/12',
[0]     __v: 0
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     _id: 5ffd227a76485d31bf43aacc,
[0]     address: '220 Cadman Plaza West undefined, New York, 11201, United States',
[0]     latitude: 40.698127335002695,
[0]     longitude: -73.99188065224,
[0]     pictureLink: 'Test',
[0]     description: 'Test',
[0]     date: '2021/1/12',
[0]     __v: 0
[0]   }
[0] ]
```

My issue is that the loadHouses function will not save into this.state.data.  When I try to print res (        console.log(res);), I get undefined which is strange since when I printed the result in the backend request (console.log(result)), I got the correct output.  Does anyone know the source of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axios calls are promises, so when `loadHouses` returns an axios call, it's returning a promise - meaning you either have to await it or do a `.then` chain off it, e.g.

```
this.props.loadHouses()
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            data
        });
    })
```

Also, state changes in React are asynchronous so you can't call `console.log(this.state.data)` right after calling `setState` and expect it to be changed. Simplest solution is to just print your state at the top of your render function, as render is called *after* state is updated and thus will have latest value